# Locking Screen Strange Error

Tags: android

I've poked around and tried some android codes, and I stumbled upon a locking code:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
mDPM.lockNow();
```

When I put it in a default code, it came up with an error that said:

"Variable mDPM" is not initalised.

I am not sure if I am supposed to initalise the variable, because the android guide specifically said to do the exact code. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

P.S. Also, I've heard to perform this lock I need to add a permission to the manifest, but I am unsure what it is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Variable mDPM" is not initalised.

This is [Basic Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/). **Non primitive types must be initialized.**

In this line

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
```

`mDPM` variable has memory reserved and it's of the type `DevicePolicyManager`, but it has not been initialized or referenced to a valid object.

---

You can get an instance as follows:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM =
    (DevicePolicyManager)getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

Find code example at SDK folder

```
<sdk_root>/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/apis/app/DeviceAdminSample.java.
```

Check here the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html) and [Developers Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Comment: So can I just put the instance anywhere? I am a bit of a beginner, so I am unfamiliar with jargon.

Comment: actually, if you app is only a `MainActivity`, yes. But it's more complex than this... please check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048960/lock-screen-with-devicepolicymanager) and links I provided for better understanding, don't hesitate to ask if furter doubts or you get stucked